# How can I add a second logo to the right of this template?

Tags: graphics, thesis, logos

Basically, what I'm trying to do is add a second logo to the right top part of this template, but when I try to put it, the code would put it at any other location. I want to put the text "Universidad Autonoma de San Luis Potosi" between the two logos. [image: The cover of the template I' using]

My code is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}



\pagestyle{fancy}
\spanishdecimal{.}


\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{teorema*}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ejemplo}{Ejemplo}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corolario}[chapter]
\newtheorem{conjetura}{Conjetura}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposicion}{Proposici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{proposicion*}{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{observacion}{Observaci\'on}[chapter]




\newcommand*{\portada}{\begingroup
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  %|
\vbox{%
%\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{5pt}
%\flushleft{
\parbox[m]{0.2\textwidth}{
\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{logo.jpg}\\
\vbox{%
\vspace*{-3\baselineskip} } } \hspace*{-0.06\textwidth}
%\flushright{
\parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\centering
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\settowidth{\unitlength}{\LARGE }  
\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}
{\Large \bf Universidad Aut\'onoma de San Luis Potos\'i}\\%[\baselineskip]
} \vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{18pt}
\vbox{%
\centering
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{0.5pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{1.3pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
\rule{0.76\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\ [-\baselineskip]
%}
\vspace*{10pt}} \vspace*{10pt}} }
\vspace*{-5\baselineskip} %
%\vfill

\hbox{%
\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{10pt}
\hspace*{0.06\textwidth}%
\rule{0.5pt}{0.72\textheight}\hspace*{0.03cm}
\rule{0.5pt}{0.72\textheight}\hspace*{0.03cm}
\rule{0.5pt}{0.72\textheight}
%%
\rule{1pt}{0.72\textheight}\hspace*{0.05cm}\rule{3pt}{0.72\textheight}
\hspace*{0.1\textwidth}%

\parbox[t]{0.75\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
{\centering \vspace{0.20\textheight} { \noindent \bf \Large{
Din\'amicas de G\'enero en el Liderazgo: An\'alisis de las Soluciones del Sistema}}
\\
%[2\baselineskip]
\vspace{2cm} {\Large\itshape \scshape T \ E \ S \ I \ S }\\
[2\baselineskip]
{\small  Que para obtener el t\'itulo de    } \\ [1\baselineskip]%\par
{\Large \bf Licenciado en Econom\'ia}\par
\vspace{0.7cm} {\Large  P R E S E N T A:    }\\ %\par
\vspace{0.7cm} {\Large \bf David Ulises Sifuentes Aranda}\\ [1\baselineskip]%\par
{\Large  Director de tesis:    }\\ [0.6\baselineskip]%\par
{\Large  Dr. Iv\'an T\'ellez T\'ellez }\\ [1\baselineskip]
{\Large  Codirector de tesis:    }\\ [0.6\baselineskip]%\par
{\Large  Dr. Jorge Zazueta Guti\'errez }\par
\vspace{0.12\textheight}
{\hspace{-0.5cm}\noindent San Luis Potos\'i, SLP.  \hfill Septiembre de 2021                   
}%\\ [\baselineskip]
}}% end of vbox
}% end of parbox
}% end of hbox
\vfill %\null
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Referencias}

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{empty}
\portada
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: how to compile this code

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // Can you please edit your question and insert a screenshot of your current "misplaced" second graphic? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I simplified "portada" using minipages for the different parts. Replace `example-image-a` with your logos.

It is not necessary to use `\\` or `\par`  to start a new line. Just leave a blank line.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\spanishdecimal{.}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{teorema*}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{ejemplo}{Ejemplo}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definicion}{Definici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corolario}[chapter]
\newtheorem{conjetura}{Conjetura}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposicion}{Proposici\'on}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{proposicion*}{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{observacion}{Observaci\'on}[chapter]


\usepackage{showframe}% for margins

\newcommand{\portada}{%
    \noindent  \begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}{%
    \centering  
    \large \bfseries Universidad Aut\'onoma de San Luis Potos\'i}
    
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{1.3pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt}
    \rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}\\ [-\baselineskip]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\vspace*{25pt}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.1\textwidth}     
    \rule{0.5pt}{0.9\textheight}\hspace*{0.03cm}
    \rule{0.5pt}{0.9\textheight}\hspace*{0.03cm}
    \rule{0.5pt}{0.9\textheight}
    \rule{1pt}{0.9\textheight}\hspace*{0.05cm}
    \rule{3pt}{0.9\textheight}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    
    {\bfseries \large   Din\'amicas de G\'enero en el Liderazgo: An\'alisis de las Soluciones del Sistema}\vspace*{45pt}
    
    {\Large\itshape \scshape T \ E \ S \ I \ S }\vspace*{35pt}
    
    {\small  Que para obtener el t\'itulo de }\vspace*{25pt}
    
    {\Large \bfseries Licenciado en Econom\'ia} \vspace*{25pt}  
    
    {\Large  P R E S E N T A:}\vspace*{25pt}
    
    {\Large \bfseries David Ulises Sifuentes Aranda}\vspace*{25pt}
    
    {\large  Director de tesis:}\vspace*{12pt}
    
    {\large  Dr. Iv\'an T\'ellez T\'ellez }\vspace*{20pt}
    
    {\large  Codirector de tesis:}\vspace*{12pt}
    
    {\large  Dr. Jorge Zazueta Guti\'errez }\vspace*{55pt}
    
    {San Luis Potos\'i, SLP.  \hfill Septiembre de 2021}        
    
\end{minipage}\hfill
\rule{.1\textwidth}{0pt}
}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{Referencias}
    
    \frontmatter
    
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \portada

    \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}   
    
\end{document}
```